# Array to String Conversion when not echoing

Tags: php

I am comparing the contents of two different databases that contain product data (one for my brick and mortar store, and one for my webstore).  I do an array_diff to check for the new/old values, and then take that output and compare it to another array using array_diff, and get the array to string conversion error.  I am presenting the two lines that should be the main issue, if you need more information, please ask and I am happy to provide.  $webArray and $pdArray are both outputs from a mysqli query. The point of these two lines is to subtract the inventory ids from the brick and mortar from the webstore inventory (to get the list of sold items), then subtract that result from the webstore database. Thank you guys so much!

```php
$soldItems = array_diff ($webArray, $pdArray);
$finalArray = array_diff ($webArray, $soldItems);
```

Sample code of what's contained in each array:

Sold items Array data

```
Array ( [product_id] => 75759 )
```

Sold items Array data:

```
Array ( [product_id] => 75839 )
```

Web Array data:

```
 Array ( [product_id] => 61822,
         [product_id] => 61825 )
```

Apparently pdArray is empty. But why would that throw that error instead of just returning the array without changes?
So, I checked the Duplicate answer thread, and their problem was that one array was single-dimensional and the other was multi. The sample output above shows that they are multi dimensional.

Comment: Can you please show snippets of your arrays, $webArray, $pdArray and $soldItems?

Comment: Can you please remove the comment and update your question with sample data?

Comment: You can't get on error that is related to **2 rows**, read the error, track the file that was mentioned in the error and the check the specific row you see in the error. Your code has nothing to do with the error you're getting

Comment: It tells me on line 70. Line 70 (in it's entirety) is present in the above snippet.  That's why I'm so confused. What I have up there has nothing to do with the error, but that's the line it's telling me.

Comment: Do you need array diff only based on product_id or the entire array?

Comment: Just product id, but that itself is in an array (and the only value contained in the array), so I thought that'd be the way to go.  Is there another way I could use? And thank you, again, for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think array_column is far easier to read than a function with serial and unserial and array_map.
Array_column flattens an array and returns an array that you can use with array_diff.

```
$soldItems = [
  ['product_id' => 75759],
  ['product_id' => 75839]
];

$webItems = [
  ['product_id' => 61822],
  ['product_id' => 61825],
];

$paidItems = [
  ['product_id' => 61822],
];

$diff = array_diff(array_column($webItems, 'product_id'), array_column($soldItems,'product_id'));
$diff = array_diff($diff, array_column($paidItems, 'product_id'));

print_r($diff); //61825
```

https://3v4l.org/IcPlb

The reason you get array to string error is because array_diff expects string, float or integer inputs not arrays.

Comment: This answer requires it to always be on product_id, if you ever want to compare on other elements, then this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will give you array_diff on multi-dimensional arrays.

```
$soldItems = [
  ['product_id' => 75759],
  ['product_id' => 75839]
];

$webItems = [
  ['product_id' => 61822],
  ['product_id' => 61825],
];

$paidItems = [
  ['product_id' => 61822],
];

$diff = getProductDiffs($webItems, $soldItems);
$diff = getProductDiffs($diff, $paidItems);

print_r($diff);

function getProductDiffs($arr1, $arr2) {
  $diff = array_diff(array_map('serialize',$arr1), array_map('serialize',$arr2));
  return array_map(function($item){
    return unserialize($item);
  }, $diff);
}
```

Comment: So, you think that it is registering as a multidimensional array? Am I reading the above output wrong, then? Or is it because it assigned it a key=>value pair?

Comment: You sample snippet is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: @TradingPostLLC, you are welcome. Did it work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: @TradingPostLLC, umm, you accepted my answer and then rejected it for another one. Hmm, ok... : /

Comment: Sorry if that was a bad move, the other answer was simpler to implement and seemed to take care of the question, so I thought for anybody else that looks this up, it would help them to know which answer seemed the simpler to use.  Was this not the right way to do that? I haven't used stackoverflow that many times, so I am still learning some of the minutiae of how to proceed, lol.

Comment: No worries. It is your question. If you feel the other answer answered your question, then that is your accepted answer. I'm just glad you found a resolution to your problem.